# dynamic PDF v/s HTML to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf, highcharts

I am currently working on multiple dashboards for the healthcare industry and one of the common requirement is generating PDF from the screen as is. We dont have any common CRUD operations on these dashboards. They typically include a lot of charts (using highcharts), some tabular data, accordions etc. And everything is rendered as a part of few select statements which will be fired on the page load or if a user clicks on some chart or any HTML element.

I am looking into ways to do this and there are 2 options, out of which the most wel-known option is to use third party libraries to generate PDF from the HTML itself which consists of the minimal effort of writing about 3-4 lines of code.

The other option is to write code to dynamically generate PDF which looks like the UI. This will require much more effort since we have to take into consideration the branding and styling, generate charts that look exactly like on the dasboard UI, create tabular data just like on the UI of the dashboard.

The common UI requirement of all the dashboards is to support all major browsers - IE starting from 9, forefox, Chrome, Safari. Also support iPads, last 3-4 versions of iPhones and other most common devices.

The technologies that we use for these dashboards are angular 2.0, some JQuery, HTML, CSS and asp.net web api and in some cases asp.net MVC.

I need to know the pros and cons of above two ways to generate PDF for all these dashboards. I googled about this found very little. Can somebody share some insight into this and give some inputs based on their experience?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you describe, you'll want to do at least a mix of the two.  It's always better if you can use an HTML-to-PDF converter because that saves a lot of development time.  But since the UI has things like accordions and such, this means you need to determine how to present that dynamic information in a static PDF.

So the hybrid approach I've used in the past is to use Angular to markup the HTML like this:

```
<my-accordion ng-if="!ExportingPDF"> ... accordion view for browser ...</my-accordion>
<div ng-if="ExportingPDF"> ... expanded and slightly-modified view for PDF ... </div>
```

When the user clicks on an "Export PDF" button, you can create a function that will do a `$scope.ExportingPDF = true` and then grabs all the visible HTML on the page (after a short `$timeout` delay to give Angular time to update the DOM).

Then your ExportPDF function will `POST` the HTML to the server where a server-based HTML-to-PDF code library will convert the HTML and then send it back to the browser as a file download attachment.

Example code:

```
$scope.ExportPDF = function() {
    $scope.ExportingPDF = true;
    $timeout(function() {
        $ajax.post("/path/to/conversion-routine.abc", { data: $('html')[0].outerHTML }
    }, 50); // short delay so Angular has time to update the DOM
}
```

This lets you utilize the power of Angular and your existing markup while still dealing with all the weird little UI things that need to be adjusted to present properly in a static PDF document.